# Minimum value of a function in a set

Tags: analysis

Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$, where $A=\{ (x_1, \ldots , x_N) \in (0, \infty)^N: \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n \neq 1\}$
$$f(x_1, \ldots , x_N) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{1}{1-\sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n}$$
Show that $f(\frac{1}{N+1}, \ldots , \frac{1}{N+1})$ is the minimum value in $$B=\{ (x_1, \ldots , x_N) \in (0, \infty)^N: \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n < 1\}$$

I show that $f$ has local minimum point at $(\frac{1}{N+1}, \ldots , \frac{1}{N+1})$
but a don't know how to show that $f(\frac{1}{N+1}, \ldots , \frac{1}{N+1})$ is the minimum value in $B$ Please help me.

Comment: $1/x$ is a convex function for $x > 0$ and apply Jensen's inequality. alternatively, you can apply AM $\ge$ GM $\ge$ HM.

Comment: $$\frac{N+1}{f(x)}=HM(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N,1-\sum_{n=1}^N x_n)\leqslant AM(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N,1-\sum_{n=1}^N x_n)=\frac{1}{N+1}$$
Thus $$f(x)>(N+1)^2 >\frac{N}{N+1}+N+1=f(\frac{1}{N+1}, \ldots , \frac{1}{N+1})$$
it is correct?

Comment: The last line should be $f(x) \ge (N+1)^2 = N \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{N+1}\right)} + \frac{1}{1 - N\left(\frac{1}{N+1}\right)} = f(\frac{1}{N+1}, \ldots , \frac{1}{N+1})$